# Customize redactor to support only hyperlinks and plain text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-editor, redactor

I am using `redactor-rails` as a editor.
I want it to customize that it will allow only hyperlinks and plain text.

If I am copy any html content and paste in editor then all formatting should be convert into plain text but links in copied text should be inserted.

I have tried following:

```
$('.company_redactor').redactor(
    { pastePlainText: true }
 );
```

But what can I do for links with plain text.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `convertLinks` like this :

```
$('#redactor').redactor({ pastePlainText: true, convertLinks: false });
```

[documentation](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/#set-convertLinks)